# I can't integrate updates to system

Tags: root-access, system-error, system-apps, systemless-root, miui-10

I am using Xiaomi Redmi 5 Plus. Unlocked the bootloader and installed TWRP recovery. Then installed Magisk as root agent. Everything seems to be working fine. But I can't integrate updates of the system app to the system. And when I try doing it, it responds with failed. And it seems something breaks and many of my finely running apps no more can launch. They all crash as soon as I open them.

Comment: try out FlashFire

Comment: seems the FlashFire is an outdated firmware flasher app. But what my issue is might be specific to Xiaomi devices or Oreo or may be Magisk. Whenever I try to change something of system apps the problem starts. The nicely working apps start crashing.

Comment: Have you found the solution?